# How to apply projections on FK property in Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11978226/637677) I am now able to store my projection logic in an `Expression` and use it inside another projections.

However, when I started to implement this approch in my solution, I found out, that I am not able to use the stored `Expression` on a Navigation property which is a single FK (not a collection).

The following code demonstrates this issue:

```
namespace Entities
{
    public class BlogPost
    {
        public virtual int BlogPostId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }

        public virtual string NotUsed { get; set; }

        public virtual User Author { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string NotUsed { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Models
{
    public class BlogPostModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public UserModel Author { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public static class BlogPostModelExtensions
    {
        public static readonly Expression<Func<BlogPost, BlogPostModel>> ToModelConverterExpression =
            p =>
            new BlogPostModel
            {
                Title = p.Title,
                Author = null, //Problem!
                // I need to convert User (p.Author) to UserModel using UserModelExtensions.ToModelConverterExpression
            };
    }

    public static class UserModelExtensions
    {
        public static readonly Expression<Func<User, UserModel>> ToModelConverterExpression = 
            u => new UserModel{ Name = u.Name, };
    }
}
```

Is it possible to convert single FK navigation property to a model using `Expression`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently possible in an overly complicated manner:

```
p =>
new BlogPostModel
{
    ...,
    Author = new[] { p }.AsQueryable().Select(UserModelExtensions.ToModelConverterExpression).FirstOrDefault()
}
```

However, the generated SQL, while correct, is needlessly complicated and slow. As far as I know, there is not yet any way to directly get what you want, but I've been looking for the same thing, and I have a proof-of-concept patch for the open source to-be-EF-6.0 that I plan to submit for inclusion, see [the discussion thread](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/394377) and [the change](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/hvdijk/entityframework/changeset/eb7219a484c3).

Comment: Well, that really is complicated. It sucks, that I can't even use helper method, because 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize it'. It would be very nice if you submit your addition to the EF here when it is ready. Until then, I will use this cumbersome solution you posted here. Thanks!

Comment: @jakubka I've now brought it to EF CodePlex and included the links in my answer, sorry for the delay.

Comment: The solution looks a little bit dirty to me, but it certainly is better that what we have now! I will try to integrate it in our project and come back with some results. I am looking forward to see generated SQL. Thanks a lot!